# Hover object, change main background

Tags: html, css, background

Can't figure this one out for some reason. Here's a basic example. Need to change the main background when hovering on a deep div (in this case, p "1").

```css
main {
  background: yellow;
}

.change:hover ~ main {
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <div>
    <p class="change">
      1
    </p>
    <p>
      2 </p>
    <p>
      3 </p>
  </div>
</main>
```

Comment: Change `~` in your css to `>`

Comment: Can't work. you can't target a parent element from its child. Unless with JS tho.

Comment: Oh yeah. Sorry.  [this](http://jsfiddle.net/Tymek/yrKRX/) may help though